# How can I get a count of how many times a number is present in records in a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
public static List<PhraseSource> phraseSources;
```

The list has property:

```
public int? JishoJlpt     { get; set; }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get a count of each of the different values of JishoJlpt using LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
phraseSources.GroupBy(p => p.JishoJlpt)
    .Select(g => new { JishoJlpt: g.Key, Count: g.Count() });
```